# UITableView always returns 2147483647

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get the number of rows in a UITableView using [myTable numberofRowsInSection:1] and I always get 2147483647. No matter how many rows are actually displayed. All I want to do is get a number for the number rows that will be displayed in the table given the data source. The data populates fine.

Comment: Do you have multiple sections in your TableView? Sections numbers are 0 indexed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have only one section, then your section index is `0`.

The value you receive is:
`2147483647 = NSIntegerMax = NSNotFound`

Comment: Tried that a day ago it always returns zero.... However, thanks for NSINtergerMax tip. I think I may just have to do a dirtier hack at this point... been spending way too much time on a tiny UI thing.

Answer (score 3):

index would start from 0, 
hence if you have only one section , you have to write

```
[myTable numberofRowsInSection:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one section then section index starts from 0.

```
[yourTableNAme numberofRowsInSection:0];
```